# Replace the first line and save to a file in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do this in Matlab, but it shows that

> Error using fgets. Invalid file identifier.  Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.

Can anyone help solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

The followings are my syntax:

```
function [ ] = replaceStr(fidInFile, DIF(k), DIF(k+1))
for k = 1:100
    fidInFile = fopen(['Rasch' num2str(k) '.inp'],'r');
    fidOutFile = fopen(['Rasch' num2str(k+1) '.inp'],'w');
    nextLine= fgets(fidInFile);
    while nextLine >= 0   
        nextLine = strrep(nextLine,['DATA=DIF' num2str(k) '.dat'], ['DATA=DIF' num2str(k+1) '.dat']);
        fprintf(fidOutFile,'%s', nextLine);
        nextLine=fgets(fidInFile);
    end
    fclose(fidInFile);                         
    fclose(fidOutFile);                       
end
```

Comment: can't you just use `textscan`?

Answer (score 0):

To read in a file, change the first line, and write it back out you can do the following:

```
% open files
fidIn = fopen('test.txt');
fidOut = fopen('test2.txt','w');

% read in file
tline = fgets(fidIn);
index = 1; 
while ischar(tline)
    data{index} = tline;     
    tline = fgets(fid);         
    index = index + 1;
end

% replace first row
data{1,1} = 'Something else';

% write to second file
for l = data
    fprintf(fidOut,'%s\n', l{1,1});
end

fclose(fidIn);
fclose(fidOut);
```

The error you're getting is probably because the file name or path your are using is invalid.